# jQuery ID selector returns blank array when I'm staring at the element

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jstree

I'm a bit new to JavaScript and I'm hitting a brick wall with this bit here.

I have a jsTree built with unique IDs based on filenames. For example,

```
<a id="node_:Folder4" href="#">Folder4</a>
```

Running a selector for

```
$("#node_:Folder4")
```

is returning [ ]. Here's a picture of the exact issue I'm seeing. Any thoughts?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/98cUQ.jpg

Comment: perhaps it doesn't like the colon.  The colon is used by the selector in several places already

Comment: The colon is used for pseudoclasses and is not valid in an ID.

Comment: Whether escaping allows this or not, I can't think of a compelling reason to absolutely require a colon. Skip on the colon and be happy. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the colon:

http://jsfiddle.net/MZA3b/1/

```
$('#node_\\:Folder4')
```

Not sure why, but I found this document here that says

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

I'm probably looking at deprecated document, but yes, try to avoid using special characters on attributes values

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  HTML spec dictates that you can use almost any character in your ID, however in order to refer to it, "special" characters must be escaped so they are taken literally.  This is also mentioned in the jQuery documentation in the selectors section.

Comment: Ah excellent, this appears to be working properly. Thank you much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters - in this case, the colon.

```
$("#node_\\:Folder4")
```